# Output a CSV file without downloading it

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a simple View and I want the response to be a csv file but I don't want the explorer to download it.

Here I show you the response I'm giving:

```py
    def csv_response(self, fields, queryset=None, filename=None):
        if not queryset:
            try:
                queryset = self.get_queryset()
            except AttributeError:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured('This method needs to have a queryset configured.')
        if not filename:
            filename = self.__class__
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline'

        writer = csv.DictWriter(response, fieldnames=fields.keys(), delimiter=',')
        writer.writeheader()

        for element in queryset:
            writer.writerow({fieldname: getattr(element, field) for fieldname, field in fields.items()})
        return response
```

I just want it to output it in any explorer instead of downloading it, is it even possible? I think it is as I've seen some on the Internet.

EDIT: I have tried to change:

```py
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/plain', charset='utf-8')
```

and then the output doesn't dowloads immediately but the characters with accents doesn't have the proper symbols. I don't understand this last par as i set the charset='utf-8'. As a check, I saw that the headers in the final html displayed by de explorer doesn't have the charset parameter set.

Comment: try changing the content_type to 'text/plain', what happens?

Comment: Then it doesn't download it, but it fails to write well some characters with '`' like À.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved inspecting the code of other csv files on the net. Thanks to @Tal as his answer was the one guiding me that way.

Code working as I wanted to:

```py
    def csv_response(self, fields, queryset=None, filename=None):
        if not queryset:
            try:
                queryset = self.get_queryset()
            except AttributeError:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured('This method needs to have a queryset configured.')
        if not filename:
            filename = self.__class__
        response = HttpResponse()
        response['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline'

        writer = csv.DictWriter(response, fieldnames=fields.keys(), delimiter=',')
        writer.writeheader()

        for element in queryset:
            writer.writerow({fieldname: getattr(element, field) for fieldname, field in fields.items()})
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible , Instead of returning a response object, you can use tabulate to convert the csv to html and return the html/or any text format you need , which you can use in your view.

More details on how to use tabulate

[link to tabulate document](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate/src/master/)

Comment: I would prefer not having to use an external library if not explicitly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return a `String` response of the CSV, and this way it will be shown in the browser without downloading

```
from io import StringIO

def csv_response(self, fields, queryset=None, filename=None):
    if not queryset:
        try:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
        except AttributeError:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured('This method needs to have a queryset configured.')
    if not filename:
        filename = self.__class__

    output = StringIO()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fields.keys(), delimiter=',')
    writer.writeheader()

    for element in queryset:
        writer.writerow({fieldname: getattr(element, field) for fieldname, field in fields.items()})
    return HttpResponse(output.getvalue())
```

Comment: It actually does, but then it doesn't break from row to row, the rest is perfectly fine. Any way to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't break from row to row" ?

Comment: That it doesn't have line breaks from row to row.

Comment: I see. Try adding `writer.writerow(os.linesep)`

Comment: It won't work as the writer pertains to the class DictWriter and the method writerow needs a key to write in the respective column. Could i just write it usin the StringIO file type?

Comment: `writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fields.keys(), delimiter=',', lineterminator=os.linesep)`